# Angularjs How to update partial template

Tags: angularjs, service, controller

I would like to know how to make controller function work whenever I change the state.
This is the main template of my Angular app:

```
<div>
    <div ng-include="'/navigation.html'"></div>
    <div>
        <!-- Page wrapper -->
        <div ng-include="'/topnavbar.html'"></div>
        <!-- Main view  -->
        <div ui-view></div>
        <!-- Footer -->
        <div ng-include="'/footer.html'"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In navigation panel I have ng-repeat:

```
<ul ng-controller="NavigationCtrl" class="nav nav-second-level">
    <li ng-repeat="user in users" ui-sref-active="active">
       <a ui-sref="account">{{user.name}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So, whenever I change the state, I would like to update this scope var **users**.
I think this is well known problem, but I am new in Angular so help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I see two ways here:

1) Listening for state events, and do callback that updates user data. Docs here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events

2) I assume that users array comes from service, something like:

```
...
$http.get('/users', function(data){
  return data;
});
...
```

so, instead of this, you can store an array locally in service(which is singleton), and update it from any places, it that way you'll have a link to array in 'NavigationCtrl', and data will be updated there as well.

What I mean:

```
function UserService($http) {
  var users = []; //inital array
  var updateUsers = function() {
     //get to update users here
  };
  var getUsers = fucntion() {
    return users;
  }

  return {
    updateUsers : updateUsers, //this method will be called when you need to update user list
    getUsers : getUsers //this method will be called in NavigationCtrl
  }
}
```

**Update:**

Here what I meant in pt.2 http://plnkr.co/edit/U2XwXNEqAxRrEa0VpYAu?p=preview

Comment: Thanks! I prefer the second way, and I actually did like this, but here is the question, if I update data in service, then how can I call in NavigationCtrl getUsers function and update Navigation template data?

Comment: the point is that you don't need to do this, because you pass an array 'by reference' in getUsers method. but to make it work as expected you should not re-write users array in 'updateUsers' method, but update the inside of it. Here an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/U2XwXNEqAxRrEa0VpYAu?p=preview